# WCF web service permissions issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf

I have successfully ran a wcf web service within my visual studio 2012 environment that its only job is to copy files from one server to another.
My project consists of a console app to be located on a pc that will call the wcf web service that lives on Server A.  This wcf service when executed, will copy file from Server B to Server C.
My problem is I get an error message that the webservice does not have permission on Server B & C.
I have looked at all links on this subject and have tried different things all week.

Can anybody help with what I need if anything on the console app, or the wcf service to ensure I have rights to Server B & Server C?
My code on the console app is as follows with the wcf service code following:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Channels
Imports System.Text
Imports SysSvcmod = System.ServiceModel.Description

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Try
            Dim client As New ServiceReference1.ServiceClient
            Dim clientCredentials As New SysSvcmod.ClientCredentials()
            clientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("user").ToString
            clientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("pswd").ToString
            client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.RemoveAt(1)
            client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(clientCredentials)
            Dim returnstring As String
            returnstring = client.movefiles("")
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
            LogExceptions("module1", "page_load", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

wcf service config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ExceptionFiles" value="C:\websites\bcccis\Exceptions\"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
                        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What exceptions are you getting? What resources are you trying to access? What user is the WCF running as and how is it hosted? Your app.config file contains nothing relevant so you should remove that from the question.

Comment: Try to run Visual Studio as Administartor